# SQL Server Bulk Insert conversion error MSG 4864 HRESULT 0x80004005

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

This is my first question here (I have been lurking and learning a lot in the past few years).

I have a problem with Bulk Insert in SQL Server 2012, it returns errors.

Bulk Insert code:

```
--DROP TABLE dbname.logg20160203
BULK INSERT dbname.logg20160204 
FROM 'x:\xxxx\SYSTEMID\log20151005t.ms'
WITH 
(
       FIRSTROW = 1,
       ORDER (Id),
       CODEPAGE = 'RAW',
       --DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
       FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
       --ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
       --ROWTERMINATOR = '\r',
       --ROWTERMINATOR = '\n\r',
       --ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
       ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
       TABLOCK, --Performance
       ERRORFILE = 'x:\xxxx\SYSTEMID\err104.log',
       FORMATFILE = 'x:\xxxx\SYSTEMID\formatfile-n.fmt',
       KEEPNULLS
);
```

Errors returned:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (TStamp).

Here is the data specified in the message:

```
    2|yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss|||GTM|||cccccccc||||||
```

My format file (so that we can keep Swedish letters in the data)

```
    11.0
    14
    1       SQLCHAR             0       0       ""   1     col1               ""
    2       SQLCHAR             0       19      "\r\n"   2    col2        ""
    3       SQLCHAR             0       20      ""   3     col3              Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
    4       SQLCHAR             0       5       ""   4     col4             Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
    5       SQLCHAR             0       10      ""   5     col5              Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
    6       SQLCHAR             0       20      ""   6     col6           Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
    7       SQLCHAR             0       20      ""   7     col7            Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
    8       SQLCHAR             0       100     ""   8     col8             Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
    9       SQLCHAR             0       10      ""   9     col9           Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
    10      SQLCHAR             0       20      ""   10    col10            Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
    11      SQLCHAR             0       20      ""   11    col11              Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
    12      SQLCHAR             0       20      ""   12    col12              Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
    13      SQLCHAR             0       20      ""   13    col13              Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
    14      SQLCHAR             0       20      ""   14    col14           Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
```

err104.log

```
    Row 2 File Offset 331 ErrorFile Offset 0 - HRESULT 0x80004005
    Row 3 File Offset 637 ErrorFile Offset 306 - HRESULT 0x80004005
    Row 4 File Offset 978 ErrorFile Offset 647 - HRESULT 0x80004005
    Row 5 File Offset 1278 ErrorFile Offset 947 - HRESULT 0x80004005
    Row 6 File Offset 1627 ErrorFile Offset 1296 - HRESULT 0x80004005
    Row 7 File Offset 1946 ErrorFile Offset 1615 - HRESULT 0x80004005
    Row 8 File Offset 2300 ErrorFile Offset 1969 - HRESULT 0x80004005
    Row 9 File Offset 2597 ErrorFile Offset 2266 - HRESULT 0x80004005
    Row 10 File Offset 2940 ErrorFile Offset 2609 - HRESULT 0x80004005
    Row 11 File Offset 3261 ErrorFile Offset 2930 - HRESULT 0x80004005
    Row 12 File Offset 3564 ErrorFile Offset 3233 - HRESULT 0x80004005
```

Thanks in advance! If you have any comments on the question itself or if you need any details please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: why do you have `\r\n` for your TStamp in the format file? Isn't that set as the field terminator?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I am not certain, this is the very first time I do a Bulk Insert. I will try to leave it empty (" ") just to test what happends.

Comment: I would think you also need your "|" as field terminator. But I'd rather advice you to maybe make the XML format type file, as it's more verbose and therefore easier to read and debug (IMO)

Comment: Ok, is native or character adviced?

Comment: Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx if you haven't already

Comment: Creating a XML format file right now, updating soon with results.

Comment: Ok i created the XML format file & the Bulk Insert went through, now I am facing the problem that Swedish letters is replaced by +.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowed formats for [DATETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx):

- `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]`
- `YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]]`

The things between rectangular brackets are optional. The `T` in the first format is the character `T`. In the second version there's a space between `DD` and `hh` (if `hh` is present)

Also, your separators are missing from your format file. You need to provide valid field terminators in your format file if you specify it in the `BULK INSERT` statement. So you will need to specify `|` as field terminator in your format file. If your row terminator is `\r\n` then you need to specify that as your final field terminator in the format file.

See the official documentation on [`Create a Format File (SQL Server)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx) on how to do that.

Comment: At least that's my guess, if those format don't work I'll remove my question and look further into this.

Comment: ok, i will try this as format. Will be back very soon with update 2       SQLCHAR    0       19      "T"   2    TStamp   ""

Comment: Resulted in same message. 4864

Comment: @RogerErtas You misread what I said. The changes I speak of are about 1) the format of the date/time that is in your DATA file (not format file) and 2) the separators in your FORMAT file (ie field terminators) which should have `|` as field separator with `\r\n` as the final one for row separator.

Comment: Ok so format file 2       SQLCHAR    0       19      "\r\n"   2    TStamp  ""  and data sample: 2015-10-05T00:00:01|||GTM|||clocktic|||||| I apologize for my retardation. Thank you for your effort. I still got a 4864 after those changes. Did I misunderstand any step?

Comment: @RogerErtas But your field separators are the pipe symbols, as clearly shown by your data sample... Why then do you have `\r\n` as a field separator? The pipe symbol is your separator, so provide that as the field separator. It also wouldn't hurt to just read through the official docu link on format files I posted...

Comment: ok, I am reading the documentation after I create the XML format file.

Comment: @RogerErtas There's no specific need for an XML format file, your regular format file will do just fine as long as you provide suitable field terminators.

Comment: Sorry, I created the XML format file. I got the Bulk Insert to go through (I took what u said earlier about the TERMINATORS and hopefully if i didnt get it wrong I changed in the XML file the , terminators to pipelines (|)). Problem now is that swedish ÅÄÖ turns into + in the data tables once inserted.

Comment: OK, I solved it - Thank you everyone for your contributions to the solution. The XML format file made me understand what was going on with the codepage and the documentation TT asked me to read fixed what issues I had left. Thanks again guys, until next time :)